# Dynamically increase the size of the cell in a list view in Android based on Content size?

Tags: android, listview

I am doing a project where i am a using a custom list view, which contains a textview. Data is coming from the server. I want to change the height of the cell, based on the data size. If the content is more than two lines, i have to trim it to two lines and show a *see more button*. On clicking the *see more button* expand the cell to show full details.I googled about it. But i cannot find any useful resource.Could any one help me to solve this, any useful links or suggestions?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to first invalidate the listView forcing it to redraw the visible elements and then handle the layout change in the getView method of your adapter.
Try this:
Add a showTrimmed(int position, boolean value) method to your adapter. This will update a structure inside your adapter that keeps track of the list items that you want to trim or not trim. Then in the getView method, when creating the item view, you test if the current element should be trimmed or not and based on the result you create the proper view.
I did something similar to achieve a different but similar result and it works.
Remember to call invalidate after calling showTrimmed to force the listView to redraw the displayed items.

Edit: I post my code which is different from what you want to do but it's quite similar in the idea:

```
public class HeroListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hero> {

public static int NO_POS = -1;

private List<Hero> heroes;
private int selected_pos = NO_POS;

public HeroListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Hero> heroes){
    super(context, R.layout.hero_list_item_view, heroes);
    this.heroes = heroes;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = GuiBuilder.createHeroListItemView(heroes.get(position),getContext(),parent,false);
    if(position == selected_pos){
        rowView.setBackgroundColor((rowView.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_selected_color)));
    }
    return rowView;
}

public void setSelectedPosition(int selected_pos){
    this.selected_pos = selected_pos;
}

public int getSelectedPosition(){
    return selected_pos;
}

public Hero getSelectedHero(){
    if(selected_pos>=0 && selected_pos<heroes.size())
        return this.getItem(selected_pos);
    else
        return null;
}

}
```

instead of setSelectedPosition you should have the showTrimmed method which updates an inner member as setSelectedPos does, in order to keep track of the trimmed state of every list item. Then in the getView method you do the test (like I do in if(position == selected_pos)) and then you build your custom trimmed or not trimmed list item based on the result of the test. My listener which uses these functions is:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        list_adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        listView.invalidate();
        }
    }
);
```

you can try to update this idea to your needs. In particular in my case I do this to highlight the clicked listview item by programmatically changing its background.

Comment: hi, i didn't get you fully...can you paste the relevant code if possible

Comment: I posted my code. Take a look to see if you can adapt the idea to your needs.